# What is the right way to manage powershell runspace without using runspace pool?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, runspace

I need to execute some cmdlets in a remote powershell session, in a certain order: ex. if this distribution-group exists then add this user to the group but I keep getting errors about runspace state or that I created too many runspaces and I have to wait some time. I can't use a runspace pool because for each session I need to get the result of a cmdlet before executing other cmdlets.

I have tried to execute the cmdlets block script (two or three chdlets that depend on the result of the others) in the same runspace but I get the invalid runspace state because the runspace is not open. I do dispose the runspace after finithing the cmdlet block script and I do dispose the powershell session too.

After searching on this site for some answers I read someone's answer in a related question, where he said that the runspace and powershell session soud be discarded after each invoke and created again, but after a short time I get an error saying I cannot create more runspaces.

```cs
    Collection<PSObject> resultado = new Collection<PSObject>();
    try
    {
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(LiveId), SchemaUri, Credenciales);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

        if (runspace != null && Credenciales != null)
        {
            PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create();
            PS.Runspace = runspace;
            runspace.Open();

            using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {

                Command cmd = new Command(comando);

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parametro in parametros)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
                }
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);

            resultado = pipeline.Invoke();
            }
            runspace.Close();
            runspace.Dispose();
            PS.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace + "/" + comando + parametros);
    }
```

How shoud I correctly manage the runspace so I can make sure that every cmdlet  block script is executed correctly?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found this template [Runspaces Simplified (as much as possible)](https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/12/runspaces-simplified/) by Chrissy LeMaire to be extremely helpfull, all you have to do is to  pass scriptblock

Below is the template

```
# BLOCK 1: Create and open runspace pool, setup runspaces array with min and max threads
$pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, [int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS+1)
$pool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
$pool.Open()
$runspaces = @()

# BLOCK 2: Create reusable scriptblock. This is the workhorse of the runspace. Think of it as a function.
$scriptblock = {
    Param (
    [string]$connectionString,
    [object]$batch,
    [int]$batchsize
    )

    $bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring,"TableLock")
    $bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "mytable"
    $bulkcopy.BatchSize = $batchsize
    $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($batch)
    $bulkcopy.Close()
    $dtbatch.Clear()
    $bulkcopy.Dispose()
    $dtbatch.Dispose()

    # return whatever you want, or don't.
    return $error[0]
}

# BLOCK 3: Create runspace and add to runspace pool
if ($datatable.rows.count -eq 50000) {

    $runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $null = $runspace.AddScript($scriptblock)
    $null = $runspace.AddArgument($connstring)
    $null = $runspace.AddArgument($datatable)
    $null = $runspace.AddArgument($batchsize)
    $runspace.RunspacePool = $pool

# BLOCK 4: Add runspace to runspaces collection and "start" it
    # Asynchronously runs the commands of the PowerShell object pipeline
    $runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{ Pipe = $runspace; Status = $runspace.BeginInvoke() }
    $datatable.Clear()
}

# BLOCK 5: Wait for runspaces to finish
 while ($runspaces.Status.IsCompleted -notcontains $true) {}

# BLOCK 6: Clean up
foreach ($runspace in $runspaces ) {
    # EndInvoke method retrieves the results of the asynchronous call
    $results = $runspace.Pipe.EndInvoke($runspace.Status)
    $runspace.Pipe.Dispose()
}

$pool.Close() 
$pool.Dispose()

# Bonus block 7
# Look at $results to see any errors or whatever was returned from the runspaces
```